# Select duplicates from a string in java using only while(true)

Tags: java, string

I have written a function that returns a string consisting of all characters occurring more than once in the string s in the order of their first appearance. For example, selectDuplicate("aabcdca") should return "ac". But i am not getting the desired result.

```
static String selectDuplicate(String s) {
    String result;

    while(true) {
        result = checkDuplicate2(s.charAt(0), s);
        if(result != null) {
            return result;
        }
    }
}

static String checkDuplicate2(char c, String s) {
    int count = 0;

    while(true) {
        if(s.equals("")) 
            break;

        if(s.charAt(0) == c)
            count++;

        s = s.substring(1);
    }

    if(count >= 2)
        return s;

    return null;
}
```

Comment: This is something easily solved by debugging your own code

Comment: when you step through the code in your debugger which line doesn't do what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand the question right, in selectDuplicate(..) you have to iterate over all characters of string s (use a for-loop). Check for each character if it exist more than once with checkDuplicate2(..). But take care of characters which occur twice or more times: dont add them to return string.

Do something like the following

```
static String selectDuplicate(String s) {
 String result = "";
 String foundtwice;

    for(i=0,i<s.length,i++){
         foundtwice = checkDuplicate2(s.charAt(i), s);
         if(foundtwice != null && !result.contains(foundtwice) {
              result = result + foundtwice;
         }
    }
 return result;
}
```

and care which string you return in checkDuplicate2(..), i think s is the wrong one. With code above you have to return the character which occurs twice or more times.

Comment: This has really helped me a lot. Thank you so much Luker10!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use only one function thanks to a StringBuffer :

```
static String selectDuplicate(String s){
    StringBuffer doubles = new StringBuffer();
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
        if (i != s.lastIndexOf(s.charAt(i)))
            doubles = doubles.append(s.charAt(i));
    for(int i = 0; i < doubles.length(); i++)
        if (i != doubles.lastIndexOf(String.valueOf(doubles.charAt(i))))
            doubles.deleteCharAt(i--);      
    return doubles.toString();
}
```